# Jquery Ajax not submitting to PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the below codes but anytime I run it, the data is not sent to the PHP file.

Here is the ajax code:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/tired.php",
    data: { username: username },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#msg").html(data);
    },
});
```

Here is the php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo $_POST['username'];
}
else {
    echo "hello bro";
}
```

Instead of displaying the username, it is displaying 'hello bro'.

Can someone please help?

Comment: you shoud use "return"

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is difficult to understand with just that snippet on what you have done (or maybe I just don't have a debugger's eye). I just want to confirm, is that the only code that you have for sending the "username" to the outstream?

What I recommend doing is:

1. Check if the input has the data for username in it. If not then it makes sense why "Hello bro" is getting printed.
2. Generally when I send data to frontend via outstream, it's like:

   ```
    if(isset($_GET["userName"])) { 
      $someVariable = $_GET["userName"];
    }
    $paging= $someVariable;   //if its a list then getList($someVariable)
    echo $paging->toJson();
   ```
3. Check again with the data by putting single inverted-s. Sometimes, I've seen even when the code is correct such small things F it up.

Answer (score 0):

The script is actually correct.
I got to realize that my serviceworker.js file was overriding the referrer.

So I had to reconfigure my serviceworker.js file and it worked perfectly fine.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Hi Abolade, welcome to SO! Good to see that you were able to answer your own question. Make sure to mark it as accepted.